# What is the best way to install a minimal Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I would like to know what is the best way to install a minimal Ubuntu setup similar to Arch. Now seeing that the mini.iso is gone is the Ubuntu Server a good option or something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If by "minimal" you mean "no-GUI", than Ubuntu Server is the most logical way to go. There are other versions, such as `.iso` files that are custom-made for various cloud vendors, but a stock Server installation will give you everything you need out of the box.

Comment: "Best"  is subjective. What is "best"  for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I do a minimal install so I can customize Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163874/how-do-i-do-a-minimal-install-so-i-can-customize-ubuntu)

Comment: By best i mean the iso which does the formatting and user creation for me but i choose which packages to install. Obviously i want an official iso that does this. Although creating user and formatting isnt mandatory since i can do this myself but its nice when the installer does it for me and saves me time.

Comment: @matigo Does the Server install adds some packages that are not needed for desktop use? Or does it let me choose what i want to install?

Comment: Have not installed server for a while, but it used this tasksel https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel. If you choose nothing then you have a minimal install. You then can install just a gui, or a full desktop which is gui & lots of apps, but varies by flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Comment: You have apt: You can always choose what to install and what to remove. "Unused" packages seem impossible for us to predict, since we don't know your use.

Comment: See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1367302/how-to-make-a-portable-ubuntu-server) if you want a portable network after installing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still can get mini.iso of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/current/legacy-images/netboot/

and then build any type of system on top of it using Aptitude and other CLI/TUI-based lightweight tools without huge massive Snaps and cloud init.